# Have multiple == statements for variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

I am learning Python 3 currently, and it has gone swimmingly up until now.
The goal of this simple dice roller is to accept user input, being Yes/No, and roll said dice. If yes/no is not met, then tell them their answer is invalid and proceed to re-ask question.

Everything works great, except for the fact that I cannot figure out how to accept both "yes" and "y" or "no" and "n" as answers. If I add an or (answery = "yes" or "y") the script will take any answer as a dice roll for some reason. Same goes for making a list, having multiple variables (answery1 = "yes" answery2 = "y"), adding commas (answery = ("yes," "y") ect. Any help would be appreciated.

```
from random import randint


def reroll():
    answer = input("Would you like to roll the die again? Yes/No \n")
    answer = answer.lower()
    answery = "yes"
    answern = "no"

    if answer == answery:
         print(randint(0, 6))
         reroll()

    elif answer == answern:
        print("Thanks for rolling!")

    else:
        print("That's not an option.")
        reroll()


def roll():
    answer = input("Would you like to roll the die? Yes/No \n")
    answer = answer.lower()
    answery = "yes"
    answern = "no"

    if answer == answery:
         print(randint(0, 6))
         reroll()

    elif answer == answern:
        print("Thanks for rolling!")

    else:
        print("That's not an option.")
        roll()

roll()
```

Comment: please chnage you decision making like

Comment: if answer == answern or answer=='y':

Comment: elif answer == answern or answer=='n':

Comment: `if(answer.lower() in ['yes', 'y', 'ye', 'ya']`